# Remove the "-none-" option in Price Set choices?

Tags: civievent, price-sets

When using price sets, at least with radio, it adds an automatic - none - option. Why is that and how can I remove or hide it?

Sample screenshot

[image: http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/download/attachments/86213750/Membership_Price_Set_example.png?version=1&modificationDate=1372586802000&api=v2]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you set the price set field to REQUIRED, the -none- option should be suppressed automatically.

Comment: What can be done if not all price sets can be set to required?

Comment: @Dana If the field is not required, then for usability you must provide a mechanism for the user to unselect all options— what would happen if someone clicked on a radio button by accident, but didn't want to click on any. That is why the *none* option is there in the first place.

Comment: This answer creates a problem in 4.6.6 - The Receipt will show this none option as a line item which is not what is wanted.

Answer (score 1):

You can hide the -none- option by customizing the template with a simple jQuery snippet. However you should add a function to give the user a mechanism to clear the selections as mentioned above. Similar to if you use a yes/no field in a profile and it is not required Civi will insert a 'clear' option link.